# Email Template not printing the picklist value

Tags: community, email-template

```
{! IF( ISPICKVAL( 
Opportunity.Transaction_Type__c,'IP - Tensilica'), Opportunity.Billing_Plan__c , 'Else Test')}
```

-Here '`Opportunity.Billing_Plan__c`' is a Pick list value, An Email Template is not printing the value if picklist.

Comment: This appears to be some sort of limitation. Email templates properly render the use of picklist fields, but no when they're within formulas. I recommend using a formula field to capture the value of Opportunity.Billing_Plan__c as text

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce doesn't support formulas in the email template, there is already a voting going on for this.

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdgZ9UAJ/formula-editor-for-email-templates

You can either use a VisualForce Template or a formula field which will have the text value of the picklist field.

Answer (score -1):

To display picklist values in formula field we should use Text(pick list field)..!

Comment: Have you tried this? It's not going to work.